# Help setting up integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $A$ be the region in $\mathbb{R}^3$ bounded by the planes $x=0$, $y=0$, $z=2$, and the surfance $z=x^2+y^2$. Evaluate $$\int_A x\, \mathrm{d}x\, \mathrm{d}y\, \mathrm{d}z$$

Here's what I have but I'm not sure it's correct:
$$\int_0^2 dz \int_{-\sqrt{2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{2-x^2}} dy \int_0^{\sqrt{2}} x\, \mathrm{d}x.$$

I can't see it visually. Can someone please help me set it up correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation $z=x^2+y^2$ describes paraboloid in $\mathbf{R}^3$. We want those values $x\geq 0, y\geq 0$. Since we are bounded also by $z=2$, so we have $0\leq x^2+y^2 \leq 2$.

Thus, $x^2+y^2 \leq 2$, so take $0\leq x \leq \sqrt{2}$.

We know $y\geq 0$, but since we must have $x^2+y^2\leq 2$, we get $0\leq y\leq \sqrt{2-x^2}$.

Last, we must retain that $x^2+y^2\leq z\leq 2$.

So, answer should be

$$\int_0^\sqrt{2} \int_0^\sqrt{2-x^2} \int_{x^2+y^2}^{2}x~dz~dy~dx.$$

Comment: can polar coordinates be used instead?